# Send Continuous data in python with UDP socket

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I have two files,`send` and `receive` that transfer data with UDP socket. In `send` file i send continues data;But `receive` get first data.
**sendfile**:

```py
UDPSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AddressPort   = ("127.0.0.2", LocalReadPort)
bufferSize          = 1024

def SendSocket(Packet,Port):
    global UDPSocket
    global bufferSize
    print('Connecting...')
    msgFromOrigin       = Packet
    AddressPort   = ("127.0.0.2", Port)
    # Create a UDP socket at client side
    UDPSocket.sendto(Packet, AddressPort)
    msgFromDestination= UDPSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    msg = "Message from Server {}".format(pickle.loads(msgFromDestination[0]))
    print(msg)

def HD():
    for i in range (0,3):
        SendSocket(pickle.dumps(i),EnginePort)

while True:
    HD()
```

**receive file:**

```py
UDPSocket = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AddressPort = ("127.0.0.2", EnginePort)
bufferSize = 1024
UDPSocket.bind(AddressPort)
print("UDP server up and listening")

def ReceiveSocket():
    global UDPSocket
    global AddressPort
    global bufferSize

    # Bind to address and ip
    bytesAddressPair = UDPSocket.recvfrom(bufferSize)
    print('1')
    message = pickle.loads(bytesAddressPair[0])
    address = bytesAddressPair[1]
    clientMsg = "Message from Client:{}".format(message)
    clientIP  = "Client IP Address:{}".format(address)
    print(clientMsg)
    print(clientIP)
```

And **output**:

```py
1
Message from Client: 0
Client IP Address:('127.0.0.1', 57742)
```

Can you help me about it.
Thanks.

Comment: why are you doing this?  what do you want to do?  what do you think is wrong with the code at the moment?  basically see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: also note that `send`ing in a loop like that, with UDP being unreliable, will just flood any real network with data and prevent useful data from getting across.  as this is on the loopback interface, you'll just be burning electricity, but at least put a `time.sleep(0.1)` or similar in there